# Add auth token in request header in ember-file-upload

Tags: ember.js, file-upload, node-modules, request-headers, auth-token

I am using ember vesrion 2.15.1 for my application. I am using [ember-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-file-upload) node module to support file upload and that is successful. Challenge is I am not able to add auth token to the request header. My request header looks like this:

[image]
I am not able to add **userAuthToken** in request header of file upload like below which I am able to add for other api calls:

[image]

I have tried uploading the file via

```
set(file, 'headers.userAuthToken', localStorage.getItem("userToken")); // this line is creating problems
let response = yield file.upload(url);
```

But unable to add **userAuthToken** in request header.
Any fix or workaround will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass options as second parameter of `upload` method. One of possible options is `headers`. Something like this should work:

```
let response = yield file.upload(url, {
  headers: {userAuthToken: localStorage.getItem("userToken")}
});
```

You can find other possible options [here](https://github.com/tim-evans/ember-file-upload)

Comment: Gennady, that was very clean and simple way. It worked nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional headers in application adapter, for example:

```
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';

var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-Token": token
    }
});
```

Comment: He asks about `ember-file-upload`, which is an addon to upload files and does not use ember data.

Comment: Yes, you are right, in my app i use: `let headers = adapter.get("headers");` and then pas it to file.upload function

Comment: Karol, I appreciate the effort but I was asking for ember-file-upload.